# PHP - Is this a correct way to pass multiple paramaters in an If statement

Tags: php

trying to create a retieve/recover form where a user can type their first and last name to retrieve an email address.  I am not sure if I need to use an array to do this or if this way is fine as well, but I am getting a syntax error.

```
<br /> <br /><p3>Retrieve User Information</p3> <br /> <br />
 <?php


if(isset($_POST['fist_name'], $_POST['last_name']) === true && empty($_POST['first_name'] , $_POST['last_name']) === false){

 if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
retrieve('email');
 }

 }
 else{
$errors[] = '<p1 class="postad_msg">Sorry, we could not find that email address!</p1>';
 }
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="retrieve">
 <fieldset>              
     <label for="first_name">First Name * : </label>
     <input placeholder="Your first name" type="text" name="first_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($first_name); ?>" /><br /><br />

     <label for="last_name">Last Name * : </label>
     <input placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="last_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($last_name); ?>" /><br /><br />

 </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="center1">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Retrieve Email" />
 </fieldset>                        
<?php echo output_errors($errors); ?>
    <?php echo output_message($message);?>
 </form>

<?php 
   }
else{
header('Location: index');
exit();
}
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty()` does not take multiple parameters.

You need to rewrite this way:

```
... empty($_POST['first_name']) === false && empty($_POST['last_name']) === false) {
```

Comment: Do I need to nest empty(($_POST['first_name']) === false && empty($_POST['last_name'])) === false)

Comment: No, since you only have && in your if statement.

Comment: And by the way, you don't need to use both empty() and isset(). Just use empty(), which checks if your variable is set and not null / empty string / 0.

Comment: I know, I know … But you have to remind beginners of the rules!

Comment: I accepted the answer but it will not allow me to up vote.  it states that i need 15 reputation to do so. Sorry!  I accepted the answer though.  Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot about that. No worries.

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) can only ever return a boolean (`true` or `false`), so you don't need `empty($foo) === false`, just `! empty($foo)`. If it suddenly starts returning something other than `true` or `false`, something has gone very seriously wrong!

Answer (score 0):

No need for nested conditions. Simply use:

```
if( (isset($_POST['first_name']) && $_POST['first_name']) &&
    (isset($_POST['last_name']) && $_POST['last_name']) &&
    (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']) ) {

}
```

Notice that you had a typo in first_name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo, but frankly speaking and this is out of lack of knowledge in PHP, the code looks a bit confusing to me. I don't have a variable called first_last??

Comment: Oops that was supposed to be 'last_name' (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

I write it quick so I didn't test it

but I think you will find out your mistake

```
<br /> <br /><p3>Retrieve User Information</p3> <br /> <br />
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $mode_allowed = array('email', 'passwd');
 if (isset($_GET['mode']) && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed)){ 

if(isset($_POST['fist_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) ){

 if(email_exists($_POST['email']) ) {
retrieve('email');
 }

 }
 else{
$errors = '<p1 class="postad_msg">Sorry, we could not find that email address!</p1>';
 }


?>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <fieldset>              
     <label for="first_name">First Name * : </label>
     <input placeholder="Your first name" type="text" name="first_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($first_name); ?>" /><br /><br />

     <label for="last_name">Last Name * : </label>
     <input placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="last_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($last_name); ?>" /><br /><br />

 </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="center1">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up For A Vegizzle Account" />
 </fieldset>                        
<?php if (isset($errors)) { echo output_errors($errors); } ?>
    <?php if (isset($message)) {echo output_message($message); }?>
 </form>
 <?php
    }

else{
header('Location: index');
exit();
}
  }
else {
    return;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's always best to explain what you have fixed, and provide a concise example, rather than expecting someone to compare a complete block of code to find what you have changed, and then guess why.

Comment: Yes,you are right,I'll do that when I wanted to answer any question